# Prolog: Generating a sublist with members that satisfy a predicate

Tags: list, prolog

What I'm looking to do is generate a sublist from a list where each member satisfies a predicate. So in a functor called heightMatchList(Person1,HeightMatchList), I would want to look at every member of GenderMatchList by calling genderMatchList and adding the members of GenderMatchList to HeightMatchList if those members satisfy the predicate heightMatch(Person1,Person2), where Person2 is the member of GenderMatchList being examined.

This program is supposed to match people based on a few pieces of information. The reason I want to use this sublist approach rather than using bagof or findall is that I only want to search for candidates that satisfy height requirements from a pool of people that already satisfy the gender requirements. I've tried searching online for generating sublists where the members satify a predicate, but they typically come back with bagof or findall. This isn't appropriate because the searchspace isn't limited to just a list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
different(Person1,Person1):-
    !,
    fail.
different(_,_).

gender(Person,Gender):-
    person(Person,Gender,_,_,_,_,_,_).

genderPref(Person,GenderPref):-
    person(Person,_,GenderPref,_,_,_,_,_).

height(Person,Height):-
    person(Person,_,_,Height,_,_,_,_).

heightPref(Person,Height):-
    person(Person,_,_,_,Height,_,_,_).

weight(Person,Weight):-
    person(Person,_,_,_,_,Weight,_,_).

weightPref(Person,WeightPref):-
    person(Person,_,_,_,_,_,WeightPref,_).

petPref(Person,PetPref):-
    person(Person,_,_,_,_,_,_,PetPref).

genderMatch(Person1,Person2):-
    gender(Person1,Gender1),
    genderPref(Person2,Gender1),
    gender(Person2,Gender2),
    genderPref(Person1,Gender2),
    different(Person1,Person2).

heightMatch(Person1,Person2):-
    height(Person1,Height1),
    heightPref(Person2,Height1),
    height(Person2,Height2),
    heightPref(Person1,Height2),
    different(Person1,Person2).

weightMatch(Person1,Person2):-
    weight(Person1,Weight1),
    weightPref(Person2,Weight1),
    weight(Person2,Weight2),
    weightPref(Person1,Weight2),
    different(Person1,Person2).

petMatch(Person1,Person2):-
    petPref(Person1,Pet),
    petPref(Person2,Pet),
    different(Person1,Person2).

match(Person1,Person2):-
    genderMatch(Person1,Person2),
    heightMatch(Person1,Person2),
    weightMatch(Person1,Person2),
    petMatch(Person1,Person2).

genderMatchList(Person,GenderMatchList):-
    findall(X,genderMatch(Person,X),GenderMatchList).
```

EDIT:

Some test data if required:

```
person(alice,female,male,small,medium,average,average,dog).
person(barry,male,female,medium,small,average,average,dog).
person(clara,female,female,tall,tall,average,average,cat).
person(danny,male,female,small,medium,average,average,cat).
person(elise,female,male,medium,small,average,average,dog).
person(fred,male,female,tall,small,average,average,dog).
person(grace,female,female,small,medium,average,average,dog).
person(harry,male,female,medium,tall,average,average,cat).
person(isabella,female,male,tall,tall,average,average,cat).
person(jack,male,female,small,medium,average,average,dog).
person(katie,female,female,medium,tall,average,average,dog).
person(larry,male,female,tall,tall,average,average,cat).
person(mel,female,male,small,medium,average,average,cat).
person(nathan,male,female,medium,small,average,average,dog).
person(olivia,female,female,tall,small,average,average,dog).
person(peter,male,female,small,medium,average,average,cat).
person(quinn,female,female,medium,tall,average,average,cat).
person(robert,male,female,tall,tall,average,average,dog).
person(sophie,female,male,small,medium,average,average,dog).
person(tom,male,female,medium,small,average,average,cat).
person(ursula,female,female,tall,small,average,average,cat).
person(vincent,male,female,small,medium,average,average,dog).
person(wendy,female,male,medium,tall,average,average,dog).
person(xavier,male,female,tall,tall,average,average,cat).
person(yvonne,female,female,small,medium,average,average,cat).
person(zed,male,female,medium,small,average,average,cat).
```

Comment: Use `different(X, Y) :- dif(X, Y).` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a predicate that finds gender and height matches for a person:

```
person_hgmatch(Person1,Person2) :-    % Person2 is a
    genderMatch(Person1,Person2),     % gender match for Person1 AND
    heightMatch(Person1,Person2).     % height match for Person1
```

Now you can get matches for e.g. barry one by one:

```
  ?- person_hgmatch(barry,X).
X = alice ? ;
X = mel ? ;
X = sophie ? ;
no
```

Based on this you can write a predicate that gives you all the matches in a list:

```
person_allhgmatches(Person,M) :-
    findall(X,person_hgmatch(Person,X),M).

   ?- person_allhgmatches(barry,X).
X = [alice,mel,sophie]
```

I think it would be easier to have (a) predicate(s) that describe(s) all requirements for a match and only aggregate at the end instead of manipulating lists for every match-criterion from the beginning.

Concerning your definition of different/2: Are you aware of the predicate dif/2? It does what you seem to intend to do with different/2. For example your predicate heightMatch/2 could look something like this with dif/2:

```
heightMatch(Person1,Person2):-
    dif(Person1,Person2),
    height(Person1,Height1),
    heightPref(Person2,Height1),
    height(Person2,Height2),
    heightPref(Person1,Height2).
```

No need to fiddle around with the cut(!) :-)

Comment: Thanks, I had considered this approach but I wanted to find a way that prolog could efficiently find the result. However it seems like in person_hgmatch wouldn't try to satisfy heightMatch if genderMatch had already failed. I thought prolog would test all the requirements for a predicate no matter what.

I didn't know about dif, so thanks! It's good to know. But I want to show off in this assignment that I know how to use a cut, so I'm going to keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

> want to search for candidates that satisfy height requirements from a pool of people that already satisfy the gender requirements

Prolog has a relational data model, so just join all requirements:

```
match_requirements(Person, Requirements, Candidate) :-
    person(Candidate,_,_,_,_,_,_,_),
    forall(member(R, Requirements), call(R, Person, Candidate)).
```

example:

```
?- match_requirements(barry,[genderMatch,heightMatch],P).
P = alice ;
P = mel ;
P = sophie ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at the trace it seems like if the first requirement isn't satisfied then it will look for another Candidate instead of checking the second requirement. So I think this is a neat way of getting what I am looking for.

I ran a trace on match as well and it seems like it actually does similar, where if genderMatch isn't satisfied, it won't look for heightMatch. Instead it will find a new person. What is prolog doing differently in these two scenarios?

Comment: The main difference is that I put a person/8 to get a Candidate, since forall/2, being a failure driven loop, **undoes** variables bindings occurring inside its arguments. But we need the binding, obviously. Calling foreach/2 instead of forall/2 should keep the bindings, and allow to drop the person/8 call, but I didn't tought of it, and so I have not tested. Would be nice if you could test how it behaves.

Comment: foreach/2 returns the same results while dropping person/8. But the trace looks longer, so I think forall/2 with person/8 may be more efficient.